# How to find pixels and positions of image in activity?

Tags: android

I am preparing paint app, here u can draw any thing, after completing draw, I want compare with original image.Is this possible?,

I have one idea that is collect the no.of pixels and positions of original image and store in arraylist. After completing draw the image collect the pixels and positions compare with original.

But how can I collect pixels and positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with aproach you are giving.

First you have to create bitmap from canvas:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

After having bitmap you can iterate pixels with bitmap class functions.